# Is it possible to send text in WhatsApp directly from an iOS App?

Tags: ios, xcode6

I'm using openURL to send a text to a WhatsApp contact from my app, But when I use this code, open WhatsApp and then I need press to send into WhatsApp app. Could be possible send this without open WhatsApp?

I have the abid contact and the text, but i don't like open WhatsApp and then press send button. Is this possible?

```
  NSURL *whatsappURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"whatsapp://send?abid=123&text=Hello%2C%20World!"];
  if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL: whatsappURL]) {
      [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: whatsappURL];
  }
```

Comment: May be this will help you https://github.com/venomous0x/WhatsAPI

Comment: But this is in php.. And I read anything about it is legal to use WhatsAPI... but thanks for answer

Answer (score 0):

### Two recent solutions (July 2017)

I've found, tested and refered two new different solutions in [THIS OTHER ANSWER](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45227158/1920145), one is through an official Whatsapp API (because S.O. policies I had to put a link to the solution, no duplicates).