# How i get WhatsApp abid to compose a message to a specific user in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, whatsapp

How i get WhatsApp abid to compose a message to a specific user ?  i want to send a text message when i select a contact in my app.

This is my code:

```
NSURL *whatsappURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"whatsapp://send?abid=XXX"];
         if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL: whatsappURL]) {
             [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: whatsappURL];
         }
```

WhatsApp official link:
https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/iphone/23559013

Comment: Have u referred this one http://stackoverflow.com/a/17790720/5362916

Comment: ABRecordGetRecordID is deprecated in iOS 9...  I'm using the new Contacts Framework and i can't find the equivalent for ABRecordGetRecordID. (identifier field is not the equivalent of ABRecordGetRecordID)

Comment: It's not possible anymore, Whatsapp has removed the URL schema as I answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17711325/abid-in-whatsapp-url-schemes/36337907#36337907

Answer (score 12):

### Two recent solutions (July 2017)

1. WhatsApp 'Click to Chat' API feature must work on all devices:

   https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/general/26000030
2. And, this other schema (for `href` links) seems to be working also:

   whatsapp://send?text=MESSAGE&phone=+NUMBER&abid=+NUMBER