# Does whatsapp ABID (Address book ID) work in php?

Tags: php, wordpress, whatsapp

I am using wordpress site and sending user to open a particular chat on whatsapp. Its working fine in case of simple text send like this:

```
<a href="whatsapp://send?text=Hi" class="wabtn">Chat</a>
```

But i want to let the users to open a particular contact. I have seen this functionality in iOS but dont know weather its also applicable in php or not. Here is the code i am trying:

```
<a href="whatsapp://send?abid=9226266566&text=Hi" class="wabtn">Chat</a>
```

There are the links that i found for help:

https://www.macstories.net/tutorials/use-whatsapps-url-scheme-with-drafts-launch-center-pro-or-a-bookmarklet/

http://www.technetexperts.com/mobile/interact-with-whatsapp-from-ios-application/

Comment: Check this answer please; https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/ru/android/28000012

Answer (score 0):

What you are mentioning is NOT dealing with PHP, since PHP is a server-side language and you are only dealing with HTML (client-side).

Nevertheless, that being said, you should better use the official solution that replaces ABID need. I've mentioned it and another schema solution that also seems to be working (july 2017) in [THIS OTHER ANSWER](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45227158/1920145) (because S.O. policies I had to put a link to the solution, no duplicates).